# How can a Postgres UPSERT fail due to a duplicate SERIAL PRIMARY KEY value?

Tags: postgresql, upsert

Given the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE devices
(
  id            SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  device_id     TEXT   NOT NULL,
  device_name   TEXT   NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX devices_by_device_id_unique ON devices (device_id);
```

And this upsert:

```
INSERT INTO devices (device_id, device_name)
VALUES (:device_id, :device_name)
ON CONFLICT (device_id) DO UPDATE
SET device_name = :device_name
```

How is it possible to get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "devices_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(253) already exists.
```

Since the `id` column is auto-generated, it shouldn't be possible to attempt to insert the same value twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify the ID value, the sequence won't be updated automatically:

```sql
insert into devices (id, device_id,device_name) values (1,1,'one');
INSERT 0 1
insert into devices (device_id,device_name) values (2,'two');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "devices_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

You can reset the sequence to the current max value

```sql
SELECT setval(
          pg_get_serial_sequence('public.devices','id'), 
          max(id)) 
FROM public.devices;
```

Comment: > "If you specify the ID value"

But the ID is never specified.

Comment: But maybe someone did a manual insert, for testing purposes 

Comment: Concluded that thats what probably happened, thanks!